# Upload Image with FTP in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, ftp

Please Help, I want to insert image to database and put the image in the ftp and only save the image path. But, it always show "The upload path does not appear to be valid." Please help me what's wrong with my code? Please Help.. Thx

```
function insert_barang() {
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $data['base_url'] = $this->config->item('base_url');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('nama', 'nama', 'required|max_length[100]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('desk', 'desk', 'required|max_length[100]');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
         $this->load->view('tambah_barang_view',array('error' => ''));
         echo '<script>alert("Insert Barang Failed");</script>';
    }

    $config['upload_path'] = 'C:/img/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '1000';
    $config['max_width'] = '2592';
    $config['max_height'] = '1456';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    if(!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $this->load->view('tambah_barang_view',$error);
        echo '<script>alert("Data Gagal di Upload");</script>';
    } else {
        $data['id_penjual'] = $this->session->userdata['id_penjual'];
        $data['nama'] = $this->input->post('nama');
        $data['harga'] = $this->input->post('harga');
        $data['stok'] = $this->input->post('stok');
        $data['desk'] = $this->input->post('desk');
        $data['id_kat'] = $this->input->post('kategori');
        $data['jenis_hewan'] =$this->input->post('jenis_hewan');

        $upload_data =  $this->upload->data();
        $filename= $upload_data['file_name'];
        $source = 'C:/img/'.$fileName;

        $this->load->library('ftp');
        //FTP configuration
        $ftp_config['hostname'] = 'ftp.lomapod.esy.es';
        $ftp_config['username'] = '******';
        $ftp_config['password'] = '******';
        $ftp_config['debug']    = TRUE;

        //Connect to the remote server
        $this->ftp->connect($ftp_config);

        //File upload path of remote server
        $destination = '/public_html/assets/'.$fileName;

        //Upload file to the remote server
        $this->ftp->upload($source, ".".$destination);

        //Close FTP connection
        $this->ftp->close();
        @unlink($source);

        $data['imgProfile'] = $upload_data['full_path'];

        $data['base_url'] = $this->config->item('base_url');

        $this->load->model('Seller_model');

        $data['last_id'] = $this->Seller_model->InsertImage($data['imgProfile']);
        $this->seller_model->InsertBarang($data['nama'], $data['harga'],$data['stok'],$data['desk'],$data['id_kat'],$data['id_penjual'],$data['last_id'],$data['jenis_hewan']);

        $this->load->view('home_view');
        echo '<script>alert("Your form was successfully submitted!");</script>';
    }
}
```

Comment: any folder exists in `C:` drive like `img`

Comment: it is always recommended to use upload path inside of your project folder. not to a local system directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Upload Image with FTP in Codeigniter

I am assuming with the above line that you are trying to upload image on server.

You are getting the issue because you are passing the path of your local system directory `$config['upload_path'] = 'C:/img/';` which is not exist on server. So change it to something like

```
 $config['upload_path'] = APPPATH . 'img';
```

Where `img` should be a folder on your server.

**NOTE : it is always recommended to use upload path inside of your project folder. not to a local system directory**

Comment: What is appath ?
Should i setting the appath to?
because it still display "The upload path does not appear to be valid."

Comment: @NickyApriliani : APPPATH is your application folder

Comment: what should i do with this code "$source = 'C:/img/'.$fileName;
" too?

Comment: `$source = $config['upload_path']."/".$fileName;`

Comment: It's solved the problem, but now this error come up ."Unable to upload the specified file. Please check your path. " How to solve it?

Comment: Check the permission of the folder.

Comment: I'm a beginner so please tell me more about how to check it hehe
Thx for your help

Comment: http://www.networksolutions.com/support/how-to-change-file-or-directory-permissions-via-ftp/

Comment: Glad to know. if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this